# C++ Exceptions in SWIG typemaps

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to use C++ to wrap some simple C++ and encountered an issue when trying to wrap even the most basic stuff.

SWIG doesn't seem to try and catch and exception that might occurr inside a typemap.

For example for the following SIWG interface file:

```
%module badswig

std::string func();
```

SWIG Generates this:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_func(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::string result;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)":func")) SWIG_fail;
  result = func();
  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new std::string(static_cast< const std::string& >(result))), SWIGTYPE_p_std__string, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Notice that `new std::string` is unprotected at all so that if `std::bad_alloc` will be thrown it will propogate to Python and crash.

There are likely other cases as well not only SWIG using `new`.

There is `%exception` which handles this for the wrapped function (If `func()` throws) but I couldn't find anything to handle this for typemaps, especially for ones supplied by SWIG.

Am I missing something? is there someway to correctly handle this?

**EDIT:**
In response to an answer and to clarify my question, `%exception` does not achive what I want:

```
%module badswig

%exception %{
    try {
        $action
    } catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        SWIG_fail;
    }
%}

std::string func();
```

Generates this:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_func(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::string result;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)":func")) SWIG_fail;

  try {
    result = func();
  } catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    SWIG_fail;
  }

  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new std::string(static_cast< const std::string& >(result))), SWIGTYPE_p_std__string, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Notice how `new std::string` has no try catch around it.

Comment: Did you ever find a nice solution to this, except putting try/catch blocks in all of your typemaps?

Answer (score 0):

The typemap just tells SWIG what interface code to generate to convert call parameters and return value of the function. The `%exception` generates code immediately before and after the function to be wrapped, to transition exceptions from C++ to target language or to convert the C++ exception to the target language equivalent. If you use `%exception` as per the SWIG docs, you should find that your wrapper function contains the typemap code you specified for that function, and the exception code around your C++ function:

```
void swig_function(PyObj*) {
    typemap-related code to convert args from Python to C++
    exception-related code
    your-c++-func(args)
    exception-related code (catch clauses etc)
    typemap-related code to convert return value from C++ to Python
}
```

Comment: Exactly, so how do we get exception handling in the typemap-related code?